# Best approach for 1 screen contains 2 view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, parent-child, uistoryboardsegue

I want to learn parent - child concepts in iOS. I found a some app in app store and I liked the their design. They have 3 button in same view controller when the user taps a button below view changes and calls their **view controllers**. Like a TabBar.

**I tried** to create 3 xib files. When the user taps the buttons they are awaking from nib and I added them to my containerView subview. It works. But I couldn't send a data between them because there is no prepare for segue method to so i couldn't prepared them.

**I tried** to create 3 viewController in Storyboard and I use them with the Storyboard ID. It works. But still can't transfer data between them.

I didn't understand what is the best approach for solve this problem ? I researched on the web about **Custom Segues** and **Parent - Child** concepts but I couldn't find anything.

What is the **best approach** for make a container like in the image ?

Thank you.

[image: When the user taps a button, bottom containerView changes and shows their viewControllers.]

Comment: If you don't mind the sliding transition, you could place your 3 child controllers inside of a `UIPageViewController`

Comment: Yes. I can ıse UIPageViewController, CustomUIViews, Xib. But, I want to learn what is the best approach ? I don't want to solve this problem. I want to learn this concepts. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is something like a best approach, at least in general term. It really depends on your specific demands and other logic of your app.

Both creating XIB files and creating ViewControllers in Storyboard together with their ID is ok. Here it is more about your preferred way. I would say that today you will probably see more using Storyboard than XIB files.

In terms of data transition. There are several ways, if it is not some very heavy logic then delegates can do it pretty well and easy.

Comment: What about custom segues or Parent - Child concepts ? I don't know very well but it has to be someway to create with segues.

Comment: Why do you want segues so much?

Well, you can create one ViewController which can "act" as something similar to TabBarViewController then connect 3 ViewControllers using segues.

You can also do it all using one ViewController and add three buttons and three views.

Comment: I said before, I can do PageViewController, UIView, Xib, Storyboard ID. I don't want to solve this problem. I just want to know What is the best approach ? It does not depends on my specific demands for learn the right approach.

Comment: Telling you "what is best approach" will be almost certain false in some cases. As I said, it really depends on other logic of your app and design of your app. None of options you have mentioned are particularly bad or 100 % right. Aim for the option which will be easy, clean and fast to work with in terms of your specific app.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answers. But In this case; No it does not depends on the demands. My main goal and image is very clear and I want to know best approach for this.